# DAX If Value is 0 then dont use it in calculation

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, dax

I have four columns with respective weights (0.1667 or 0.3333) and if one of them (Ta, Tb, Tc, Td) are 0 I don't want them to be involved in my end calculation. Can someone help me with the denomiator part since it needs to be dynamic regarding the output?

````
var Tb= ('T2'[Col2] * 0.1667)
var Tc = ('T3'[Col3] * 0.3333)
var Td = ('T4'[Col4] * 0.3333)
Return end_calculation = Ta + Tb + Tc + Td / 0.1667 + 0.1667 + 0.3333 + 0.3333 ```

(Only take all four weights in the denomiator into account if it is not empty)
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [IF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/if-function-dax) function, and use [DIVIDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/divide-function-dax) to add support for divide-by-zero.

```
divide(Ta + Tb + Tc + Td, if(Ta>0,0.1667,0) + ...
```